# Check if the post_date was one minute ago PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I fetched into an `array` the `wp_posts` table in wordpress.
I want to make a cron job that would check if the post_date of each entry was one minute ago.

I tried this, but it doesn`t work.

```
foreach($arrayOfPosts as $post){

    $postDate = strtotime($post['post_date']);
    $formatedDate = strtotime($oneMinuteAgo);
    $currentDate= strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

    echo $postDate . "----" . $formatedDate . " <br/>";
    if ($formatedDate <= $postDate){
        array_push($arrayOfNewPosts,$post);
}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Have you confirmed the value of `$postDate`?

Comment: What is the value of `$oneMinutedAgo`?

Comment: Please display your output

Comment: FWIW, this line: `strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))` is completely worthless. You could just do `$currentDate = time();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming that `$postDate` contains what you think it does, the following code should be sufficient:

```
$postDate = strtotime($post['post_date']);
if($postDate == (time() - 60)
{

}
```

Please note that this checks if the post date is **exactly** one minute ago. To check for one minute or older, use `$postDate <= (time() - 60)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need a $formatedDate ?

```
$postDate = strtotime($post['post_date']);
$currentDate= strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

if ($postDate < $currentDate - 60) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add to the post `60 seconds` and check if the timestamp is higher then the current time.
if the time is higher the post was posted within 1 minute.

```
$postDate = strtotime($post['post_date']);
if( ($postDate + 60)  >= time() )
{
    echo "within 1 minute";
}
```